# QGIS: Value relation forms

Tags: qgis, forms, relation

Is it possible to set default value to parent, based on child entry? I know how to do it from parent to child, but I want to do it in reverse. I have two CSV files with values. First I want to edit child value, then, based on my entry, I want parent field to be populated.

Here is my `CHILD` table I use to enter values

| TYPE_ID | TYPE | FUNCTION_ID |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Coffee Shop | 10 |
| 2 | Restaurant | 10 |
| 3 | Library | 20 |
| 4 | Hospital | 30 |
| 5 | Apartment | 40 |

And this is my `PARENT` table I want to update by default

| FUNCTION_ID | FUNCTION |
| --- | --- |
| 10 | Food |
| 20 | Education |
| 30 | Health |
| 40 | Living |

So, my next entry in my child table should be `Coffee shop` my sixth entry in my data. How to define value relation, when I enter coffee shop to default value to be `10`

TLDR: When I digitize my map, first I want to enter `CHILD` data, and `PARENT` data should be updated based on tables.